# Compile mustache partials using external json data

Tags: json, partial, mustache, gruntjs

I'm using mustache partials for our internal documentation and for testing - as described in this other SO question [how to have grunt task render mustache partials to static HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521608/how-to-have-grunt-task-render-mustache-partials-to-static-html), and I'd now like to make the partials data driven using external json files. The json files would be named the same as the partials and will contain mock data that would compile with the partials.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: We now use https://github.com/assemble/assemble for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the hogan.js file to read in data.json files that have the same name as the partials:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Grunt utilities.
  var task   = grunt.task,
    file     = grunt.file,
    utils    = grunt.util,
    log      = grunt.log,
    verbose  = grunt.verbose,
    fail     = grunt.fail,
    option   = grunt.option,
    config   = grunt.config,
    template = grunt.template,
    _        = utils._

  // external dependencies
  var fs   = require('fs'),
    hogan  = require('hogan');


  // ==========================================================================
  // TASKS
  // ==========================================================================
  grunt.registerMultiTask('hogan', 'Compile mustache files to HTML with hogan.js', function() {

    var data     = this.data,
      src        = grunt.file.expandFiles(this.file.src),
      dest       = grunt.template.process(data.dest),

      // Options are set in gruntfile
      defaults   = {
        production:  false,
        docs:        false,
        title:      'Sellside',
        setAccount: 'NA',
        setSiteId:  'NA',
        layout:     'docs/templates/layout.mustache',
        paths: {},
        partials: {},
        partialsData: {},
      },

      options = _.extend(defaults, this.data.options || {})

      !src && grunt.warn('Missing src property.')
      if(!src) return false

      !dest && grunt.warn('Missing dest property')
      if(!dest) return false

    var done         = this.async()
    var srcFiles     = file.expandFiles(src)

    if(options.paths.partials) {

      var partials = grunt.file.expandFiles(options.paths.partials);
      log.writeln('Compiling Partials...');
      partials.forEach(function(filepath) {
        var filename = _.first(filepath.match(/[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$/i)).replace(/\.mustache$/, '');
        log.writeln(filename.magenta);

        var dataFilepath = filepath.replace(/\.mustache$/, '.json');

        var partial = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8');
        options.partials[filename] = hogan.compile(partial);

        // if a data file exists, read in the data
        if(fs.existsSync(dataFilepath)) {
          options.partialsData[filename] = grunt.file.readJSON(dataFilepath);
        }

      });
      log.writeln();
}

    try {
      options.layout   = fs.readFileSync(options.layout, 'utf8')
      options.layout   = hogan.compile(options.layout, {
        sectionTags: [{
          o: '_i',
          c: 'i'
        }]
      })
    } catch(err) {
      grunt.warn(err) && done(false)
      return
    }

    srcFiles.forEach(function(filepath) {
      var filename = _.first(filepath.match(/[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$/i)).replace(/\.mustache$/, '')

      grunt.helper('hogan', filepath, filename, options, function(err, result) {
        err && grunt.warn(err) && done(false)
        if(err) return

        file.write(dest.replace('FILE', filename), result)
      })
    })

    done()
  })

  // ==========================================================================
  // HELPERS
  // ==========================================================================
  grunt.registerHelper('hogan', function(src, filename, options, callback) {
    log.writeln('Compiling ' + filename.magenta);

    var page                = fs.readFileSync(src, 'utf8'),
        html                = null,
        layout              = options.layout,
        context             = {};

        context[filename]   = 'active';
        context._i          = true;
        context.production  = options.production;
        context.docs        = options.docs;
        context.setAccount  = options.setAccount;
        context.setSiteId   = options.setSiteId;

    var title               = _.template("<%= page == 'Index' ? site : page + ' · ' + site %>")
    context.title           = title({
      page: _(filename).humanize().replace('css', 'CSS'),
      site: options.title
    })
    try {
      page = hogan.compile(page, {
        sectionTags: [{
          o: '_i',
          c: 'i'
        }]
      })

      context = _.extend(context, options.partialsData);    
      options.partials.body = page;
      page = layout.render(context, options.partials)

      callback(null, page)
    } catch(err) {
      callback(err)
      return
    }
  })
};
```

A simple example of an alert.json file:

```
{
  "modifier": "alert-warning",
  "alertType": "Warning!",
  "message": "Best check yo self, you're not looking too good."
}
```

#### alert.mustache

## alerts

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="alert {{alert.modifier}}">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>{{alert.alertType}}</strong>
      {{alert.message}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- /container -->
```

I like this next example better because you can create different data to use
in the same partials:

#### alert.json

```
{
  "default": {
    "modifier": "alert-warning",
    "alertType": "Warning!",
    "message": "Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.!"
  },
  "error": {
    "modifier": "alert-error",
    "alertType": "Error!!!",
    "message": "You did something horribily wrong!!!"
  },
  "success": {
    "modifier": "alert-success",
    "alertyType": "Success!!!",
    "message": "The record has been successfully saved..."
  }
}
```

#### alert.mustache

```
<!-- partial -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>alerts</h1>

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="alert {{modifier}}">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>{{alertType}}</strong>
      {{message}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- /container -->
```

#### partials.mustache  --- this is where the alert partial is referenced

```
  {{#alert.default}}
    {{> alert }}
  {{/alert.default}}

  {{#alert.error}}
    {{> alert }}
  {{/alert.error}}

  {{#alert.success}}
    {{> alert }}
  {{/alert.success}}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: This is great, I think it's exactly what I need. However, does mustache.js syntax allow for something like this: ```{{> alert.success }}``` instead of having to wrap the partial references with templates?

Comment: that way you could do ```{{> alert }}```, ```{{> alert.info }}```,```{{> alert.success }}``` etc. I'm not even sure if this is a good idea in practice, just curious

Comment: To answer my old comment, using https://github.com/assemble/assemble you can do: {{> alert info }},{{> alert success }}